# How to upload file from a subfolder using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, file-upload

Can somebody tell me what to modify here, so the file I'm uploading can be uploaded from a subfolder? At the moment the files are stored in the same folder as the python script.

This script helps me to automate the process of adding ads to a site. Here is the part which uploads image files from a json file (photofiles is an array in config.json). I want to store the photos in a subfolder.

```
# Upload images
fileup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

for path in photofiles:
    uploaded_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("imagebox-thumbnail"))
    fileup.send_keys(os.path.abspath(path))
    total_upload_time = 0
    while uploaded_count == len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("imagebox-thumbnail")) and \
                    total_upload_time < 30:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        total_upload_time += 0.5

    log.debug("Uploaded file in %s seconds." % total_upload_time)
```

Comment: why don't you simply use `os` library.

Comment: yes, I'm already using 'import os'

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple by just modifying the photofiles list. Assuming your code creates a list of files and stores it as "photofiles" you just need to append to it all the needed paths from the folder you want.

There are multiple ways of traversing a folder and, for example, getting all the files with a certain extension (see [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)). You could build your "photofiles" list from all the files with certain extensions in your desired folder.

Comment: Hi, @BoboDarph. 
I think, He just wants to get inside the sub-dir.

His lines :-


***"Can somebody tell me what to modify here, so the file I'm uploading can be uploaded from a subfolder? At the moment the files are stored in the same folder as the python script."***

Comment: quick and dirty, as @BoboDarph suggested, I modified my config.json like this `"photofiles": [ "subfolder/photo.jpg" ]` and it worked.

I will try now to modify my python script ...

Answer (score 0):

**The file you are uploading can be easily uploaded from a subfolder.**

```
>>> import os 
>>> print(os.getcwd())
C:\Python32 
>>> os.chdir('/test') 
>>> print(os.getcwd()) 
C:\test
```

Just use **os.getcwd()** and **os.getcwd()** to enter in ***sub-dir***.

That's it. I think now, you will yourself implement the above snippet in your script.

BTW,
I recommend you to visit [Python Files](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_files.php).